# Play file mp3 in asset with file's name is number

Tags: android, media-player, assets

I have a file 100.mp3 in asset
when add this file to asset,it display error: invalid file name..I think cause is file's name is number But I want to use this name to play as code follow. How must I do?

```
AssetFileDescriptor des = mContext.getAssets().openFd("100.mp3");
                mp.setDataSource(des.getFileDescriptor(), des.getStartOffset(),
                        des.getLength());
                mp.prepare();
                mp.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

i suggest you rename the file because android will can't find the resource for the file from R.java. the file name must start with a letter but not a number.